# tools to generate the scaffolding of a package for types in DefinitelyTyped?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typing

I want to do a couple of contribution to http://definitelytyped.org/ in terms of types like https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types.

I supposed there should be something to generate a package from zero or just to start. I realized most of them have tsconfig.json, package.json, index.d.ts & test.ts.

If anyone does know any tool rather than npm or tsc, it would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) is pretty good at scaffolding:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/generator-deftyped

Creating your own generator is also super easy, and the docs about [creating generators](http://yeoman.io/authoring/) are good.

Comment: Yes, I love yeoman; in fact I used in the past. However, this one is not working for. Could you confirm is working for you? I have tried this one https://github.com/samverschueren/generator-dt#readme as well but not success

Comment: Indeed it didn't work for me; I'd suggest opening an issue with the author - I presume it would be an easy fix, and the report wouldn't remain unappreciated.

Comment: Of course, I would do. But the problem is that I don't know the main structure of a type package, what is mandatory and what is not and how I can generate certain things. If you have any link, help or whatever on it...